# How to make exact phrase searches that ignore word-ending in preview

Tags: preview, search

When I use the search phrase "2019 regula", I'm looking for results including "2019 regulation", "2019 regulatory", "2019 regulator" etc., but preview will only match the exact phrase with that exact word ending (often resulting in 0 matches). You'd think "2019 regul*" would work, but it doesn't.

Here's what it looks like when I do the search for a complete phrase:
[image: Print screen of result from complete search phrase]

And here a search for an incomplete phrase:
[image: Print screen of result from incomplete search phrase]

How can I make this type of search in preview?

Comment: This is strange. If I type a word/phrase Preview will show me **all** results that have the same beginning or same words, just like you need it. Is it possible that the pdf you're searching in may not be in the correct format? If you need to do OCR first, then I can recommend PDF Scanner for example on the AppStore.

Comment: @X_841, I've added some photos for clarification. Are you saying that you'd get a hit on the second (incomplete) search phrase? There is no OCR issue.

Comment: Yes. Also tried it with three incomplete phrases. For comparison: I am on the latest Catalina release 10.15.7. If our Preview app is the same (and I just assume that now) it **must** be the pdf.